# salesforce SOAP Xml with complex filter to retrieve records from dataextension

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Need to retrive records from address dataextension of salesforce having **address is null or empty using SOAP post call.**

Also, what is the best operator for soap which match or filter **for empty property value, right now i'm using like operator for retrieving records** having empty property values.

Following is the created request xml but unable to retrieve data from salesforce,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <fueloauth>7JVdsIGNbt0afbuPx3oUrYns</fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Otsuka_MCM_Consumer-Address_Ext]</ObjectType>
        <Properties>location_id</Properties>
        <Properties>address_type_cd</Properties>
        <Properties>address_line_1</Properties>
        <Properties>address_line_2</Properties>
        <Properties>address_line_3</Properties>
        <Properties>city</Properties>
        <Properties>state_cd</Properties>
        <Properties>zip</Properties>
        <Properties>zip4</Properties>
        <Properties>country</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
          <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>address_line_1</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
            <Value/>
          </LeftOperand>
          <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
          <RightOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
            <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
              <Property>city</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
              <Value/>
            </LeftOperand>
            <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
            <RightOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
              <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>state_cd</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
                <Value/>
              </LeftOperand>
              <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
              <RightOperand xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart">
                <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                  <Property>zip</Property>
                  <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
                  <Value/>
                </LeftOperand>
                <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
                <RightOperand xsi:type="par:ComplexFilterPart">
                  <LeftOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>address_line_2</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value/>
                  </LeftOperand>
                  <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
                  <RightOperand xsi:type="par:SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>address_line_3</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>isNull</SimpleOperator>
                  </RightOperand>
                </RightOperand>
              </RightOperand>
            </RightOperand>
          </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Able to get successful response from salesforce of same request using REST call, but unable to get same result using SOAP, following is the REST call of same SOAP api,**

````
https://{MY-Domain}/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/Otsuka_MCM_Consumer-Address_Ext/rowset/?%24filter=address_line_1%20eq%20''%20AND%20city%20eq%20''%20AND%20state_cd%20eq%20''%20AND%20zip%20eq%20''%20AND%20(address_line_2%20is%20null%20or%20address_line_2%20eq%20'')%20AND%20(address_line_3%20is%20null%20or%20address_line_3%20eq%20'')```
````

Comment: Do you actually have empty strings in these fields or nulls? SFMC normally interprets empty strings and null on import.

Comment: All the fields are having empty string values, but in SFMC response getting all records having not null as well as null fields values.